# Which JSON adapter enables Ember to propagate all necessary requests to the server to maintain model consistence?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am using Andy Crum's [EmberDataModelMaker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/).

Having punched in the following two classes

```
// app/models/server-item.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    hostName: DS.attr('string'),
    syncServers: DS.hasMany('string'),
    subscribers: DS.hasMany('string'),
    mailHost: DS.attr('string'),
    mailHostLogin: DS.hasMany('credentials')
});
// app/models/credentials.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string'),
    server: DS.belongsTo('serverItem')
});
```

It's showing the following three different expected JSON formats (a very nice feature btw.):

#### DS.RESTAdapter

```
"serverItems": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "hostName": "foo",
        "syncServers": [
            <stringids>
        ],
        "subscribers": [
            <stringids>
        ],
        "mailHost": "foo",
        "mailHostLogin": [
            <Credentialsids>
        ]
    }
],
"credentials": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": "foo",
        "password": "foo",
        "server": <ServerItemid>
    }
]
```

#### DS.ActiveModelAdapter

```
"serverItems": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "host_name": "foo",
        "sync_server_ids": [
            <stringids>
        ],
        "subscriber_ids": [
            <stringids>
        ],
        "mail_host": "foo",
        "mail_host_login_ids": [
            <Credentialsids>
        ]
    }
],
"credentials": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": "foo",
        "password": "foo",
        "server_id": <ServerItemid>
    }
]
```

#### DS.JSONAPIAdapter

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "server-items",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "HostName": "foo",
            "MailHost": "foo",
        },
        "relationships": {
            "SyncServers": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "SyncServers",
                    "id": <SyncServersid>
                }
            },
            "Subscribers": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "Subscribers",
                    "id": <Subscribersid>
                }
            },
            "MailHostLogin": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "MailHostLogin",
                    "id": <MailHostLoginid>
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                <sideloadedrelationships>
            ]
        }
    }
}
{
    "data": {
        "type": "credentials",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "User": "foo",
            "Password": "foo",
        },
        "relationships": {
            "Server": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "Server",
                    "id": <Serverid>
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                <sideloadedrelationships>
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am going to implement (or rather change) some WebServices on the Server side (using C#, ASP.NET Web API). Currently, the WebService already creates a result that is pretty similar to the format expected with DS.RESTAdapter - obviously, it would be ideal if I could use it without compromising the Data Integrity - can I?

If yes, would it empower Ember Data to send all the requests necessary to maintain the data consistency on the server? Meaning, would the client send a DELETE request to the server not only for the `ServerItem` but also for the `Credentials` item that is referenced via the `mailHostLogin` property when the user wants to delete a `ServerItem`?

If not: are both of the other two adapters fulfilling the above mentioned consistency requirement? Which of the other two should I implement - any experiences/recommendations out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose whichever Adapter closest fits your API data structure as a basis(sounds like `DS.RESTAdapter` in this case). You can extend the adapters and serializers that are a closest fit to make any necessary adjustments(this can be done both application wide or on a per model basis).

However, I don't think that the Ember Data model relationships(i.e. `belongsTo` and `hasMany`) are binding in such a way that will automatically result in the "data consistency" you are looking for. If your application requirements are to delete all associated `Credentials` records when a `ServerItem` is deleted, I would recommend doing that server side when handling the `DELETE ServerItem` API request. That would result in better performance(1 HTTP call instead of 2 or N depending if credentials can be deleted in bulk) and be much less error prone due to potential network or other failure of calls to delete Credentials after a ServerItem is deleted.

After a successful ServerItem delete, you could loop through it's credentials and unload the records from the client side store to keep it in sync with the new state on the server.  Something like:

`serverItemCredentials.forEach(function(id) {
  if (this.store.recordIsLoaded('credential', id)) {
    this.store.unloadRecord(this.store.peekRecord('credential', id));
  }
});`